# HOW TO instantiate and populate a xml object

Tags: c#, xml

I query a repo using the cmd "zypper --xmlout se -s perl-MIME-tools" so that i get back into my code an xml formatted string.

I want to be able to query and work with this xml -  how can i convert it to a xml object to do this?

my code:

```
string output = queryTargetBix("zypper --xmloutput se -s perl-MIME-tools");
```

example xml (contained in output)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream>
<message type="info">Loading repository data...</message>
<message type="info">Reading installed packages...</message>

<search-result version="0.0">
<solvable-list>
<solvable status="installed" name="perl-MIME-tools" kind="package" edition="5.427-2.10.1" arch="x86_64" repository="timbus_repo_local"/>
</solvable-list>
</search-result>
</stream>
```

How can i store this xml in an obecjt where i can get the 'edition' value easily for eg?

Comment: You should have a look at XML-Serialization which is most common way to do this

Comment: [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387098.aspx) maybe?

Comment: XML is just a string; you can query it using `XDocument`, browse it using `XmlDocument`, deserialize into a class using `XmlSerializer`, etc.

Comment: Can anybody suggest example code to get the 'edition' from the above 'output' string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XmlSerialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx) which will convert your string into a set of normal .Net object or you can use an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class which provides a way to query an XML document. The latter is easier to get set up but is harder to work with.

There is also [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) but I've never worked with this and it is only available in .Net 3.5 and later.

For example to extract the edition using an XmlDocument you would use code something like this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(stringWithXmlIn);
        XmlNode solvableNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("stream/search-result/solvable-list/solvable");
        string edition = solvableNode.Attributes["edition"].Value;
```

Comment: im struggling getting the xmlDocument to recognise this as xml and not just a random string - its innerxml is just the string in my code instead of recognising the string as valid xml format. How can i pull the 'edition' out of this xml

Comment: @Fearghal I have added an example to my answer for you.

Comment: Cheers. I got it earlier but will mark as the answer soon